# Group list while recursive looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is my sample input and output:

```
l = [
    ['random_str0', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str1', '', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str2', '', ''],
    ['random_str3', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str4', '', ''],
    ['random_str5', '', ''],
    ['random_str6', 'random_str', ''],
    ['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str8', '', ''],
    ['random_str9', '', ''],
    ['random_str10', '', ''],
    ['random_str11', '', ''],
]


out = [ # something like this. data structure and type and order are not important
    ['random_str0', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    [
        ['random_str1', '', 'random_str']
        ['random_str2', '', '']
    ],
    [
        ['random_str3', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
        ['random_str4', '', ''],
        ['random_str5', '', '']
    ],
    ['random_str6', 'random_str', ''],
    [
        ['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
        ['random_str8', '', ''],
        ['random_str9', '', ''],
        ['random_str10', '', ''],
        ['random_str11', '', '']
    ]
]
```

The idea if any inner list is having either index 1 or 2 value is followed by one or more list having missing index 1 and 2 value, it forms a group. (My actual code is more complex and have other conditions as well but for brevity, it is omitted as it is not part of the actual question.

This is how I tried.

```
for n in reversed(range(1, 5)):
    for i in range(len(l)-n):
        group = [l[i+j] for j in range(n+1)]
        if (
            (group[0][1] or group[0][2]) and
            all([not (g[1] and g[2]) for g in group[1:]])
        ):
            print(group)

Out: # not desired as it is overlapping.
[
    ['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str8', '', ''],
    ['random_str9', '', ''],
    ['random_str10', '', ''],
    ['random_str11', '', '']
]
[
    ['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str8', '', ''],
    ['random_str9', '', ''],
    ['random_str10', '', '']
]
[
    ['random_str3', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str4', '', ''],
    ['random_str5', '', '']
]
[
    ['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str8', '', ''],
    ['random_str9', '', '']
]
[
    ['random_str1', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str2', '', '']
]
[
    ['random_str3', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str4', '', '']
]
[
    ['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str8', '', '']
]
```

**The Question is** how can I track record such that the grouping doesn't overlap. I think recursive looping will help but I don't know how to accomplish that.

the final data structure is not needed to be a list. I tried it with dicts but the code becomes more complicated.

**for more clarification, I created step by step pastebin**
https://pastebin.com/qeWbxheK

Comment: What does "recursive looping" mean? Could you add something more distinct than "random_str" in your example, do we can actually see what goes where?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I do looping 5 times (n). after every loop, some groups match. while looping next time I don't want to loop again over matched group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With single loop:

```
import pprint

res = []
for sub_l in lst:   # lst is your initial list
    if sub_l[1] or sub_l[2]:
        res.append(sub_l)   # add as a base item of the group
    elif not sub_l[1] and not sub_l[2] and res:
        # check if last item is not a 2-dimensional list yet
        if not isinstance(res[-1][0], list): res[-1] = [res[-1]]
        res[-1].append(sub_l)

pprint.pprint(res)
```

The output:

```
[['random_str0', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
 [['random_str1', '', 'random_str'], ['random_str2', '', '']],
 [['random_str3', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
  ['random_str4', '', ''],
  ['random_str5', '', '']],
 ['random_str6', 'random_str', ''],
 [['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
  ['random_str8', '', ''],
  ['random_str9', '', ''],
  ['random_str10', '', ''],
  ['random_str11', '', '']]]
```

Comment: Now I totally understood your answer. As I said, my actual condition is not that simple but I will definitely help me understood how to more forward. You have definitely answered the question as presented. Thanks

Comment: @Rahul, and thank you for the interesting question )

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the list and try to grow a window of items that verify your condition (both `item[1]` and `item[2]` evaluate to `False`). To do that you can have two loops, one that will iterate over window starts, and a second that will enlarge the window while the condition is met:

```py
def cut(l):
    start = 0
    while start < len(l):
        end = start + 1
        while end < len(l) and not (l[end][1] or l[end][2]):
            end += 1
        yield l[start:end]
        start = end
```

You can then use this generator like this:

```py
for sublist in cut(l):
    print(sublist)
    print("----")
```

Which produces:

```py
[['random_str0', 'random_str', 'random_str']]
----
[['random_str1', '', 'random_str'], ['random_str2', '', '']]
----
[['random_str3', 'random_str', 'random_str'], ['random_str4', '', ''], ['random_str5', '', '']]
----
[['random_str6', 'random_str', '']]
----
[['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'], ['random_str8', '', ''], ['random_str9', '', ''], ['random_str10', '', ''], ['random_str11', '',
```

If you simply want a list of these sublists you can use `list(cut(l))` to convert the generator to a list.

Comment: I also thought something similar and tried but could not think of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
d = [['random_str0', 'random_str', 'random_str'], ['random_str1', '', 'random_str'], ['random_str2', '', ''], ['random_str3', 'random_str', 'random_str'], ['random_str4', '', ''], ['random_str5', '', ''], ['random_str6', 'random_str', ''], ['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'], ['random_str8', '', ''], ['random_str9', '', ''], ['random_str10', '', ''], ['random_str11', '', '']]
new_d = [list(b) for _, b in groupby(d, key=lambda x:not any(x[1:]))]
_d = [[*new_d[i][:-1], [new_d[i][-1], *new_d[i+1]]] for i in range(0, len(new_d), 2)]
result = [i for b in _d for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[
 ['random_str0', 'random_str', 'random_str'], 
 [['random_str1', '', 'random_str'], ['random_str2', '', '']], 
 [['random_str3', 'random_str', 'random_str'], ['random_str4', '', ''], ['random_str5', '', '']], 
 ['random_str6', 'random_str', ''], 
 [['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'], ['random_str8', '', ''], ['random_str9', '', ''], ['random_str10', '', ''], ['random_str11', '', '']]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will certainly give it a try for my use case. Can we use a function in place of lambda for groupby? I will check. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this code:

```
l = [
    ['random_str0', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str1', '', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str2', '', ''],
    ['random_str3', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str4', '', ''],
    ['random_str5', '', ''],
    ['random_str6', 'random_str', ''],
    ['random_str7', 'random_str', 'random_str'],
    ['random_str8', '', ''],
    ['random_str9', '', ''],
    ['random_str10', '', ''],
    ['random_str11', '', '']
]


tmplst=[]
for  l_itm in l:
    if l_itm.count('') <=1:
        tmplst.append([l_itm])
    elif len(tmplst) != 0:
        tmplst[-1].append(l_itm)

for i in range(len(tmplst)):
    if len(tmplst[i]) < 2:
        tmplst[i]=tmplst[i][0]

print(tmplst)
```

Comment: Didn't you check it?

Comment: I did check it.